# accepts_nested_attributes_for only display one record when used with has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

My models

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rounds
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rounds
end

class Round < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

controller

```
def new
    @game = Game.new
    3.times { @game.rounds.build }
end
```

view

```
<%= form_with scope: :game, url: games_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :game_date %><br>
    <%= form.date_field :game_date %>
  </p>

  <ul>
    <%= form.fields_for :rounds do |builder| %>
      <li>
        <%= builder.label :title %>
        <%= builder.text_field :title %>

        <%= builder.label :order %>
        <%= builder.text_field :order %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The above code only generates one "round" of record when new is building 3 records.

I am on rails 5.2.1

Comment: You can take reference from this tutorial - http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have a different object (formbuilder) when using form.

```
<%= form_with model: @game, local: true do |form| %>
```

Or

```
<%= form_with scope: @game, url: games_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

instead of

```
<%= form_with scope: :game, url: games_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

which produces the desire result. Have a look at [this blog](https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to use form_for instead of the new form_with.